# Cassandra - SERIAL is not supported as conditional update commit consistency

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

I do write from Spark (2.0.2) to Cassandra (3.7):

```
someRdd.saveToCassandra("keyspace", "table", writeConf = ifNotExists)
```

Spark-cassandra-connector (version 2.0.0-M3) consistency configuration:

```
spark.cassandra.output.consistency.level ONE
```

It worked fine for some period of time, but now it start to fail with the following exception:

```
ERROR writer.QueryExecutor: Failed to execute: com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.RichBoundStatement@6ad8868c
com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidQueryException: SERIAL is not supported as conditional update commit consistency. Use ANY if you mean "make sure it is accepted but I don't care how many replicas commit it for non-SERIAL reads"
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Responses$Error.asException(Responses.java:136)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.DefaultResultSetFuture.onSet(DefaultResultSetFuture.java:179)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.RequestHandler.setFinalResult(RequestHandler.java:173)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.RequestHandler.access$2500(RequestHandler.java:43)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.RequestHandler$SpeculativeExecution.setFinalResult(RequestHandler.java:788)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.RequestHandler$SpeculativeExecution.onSet(RequestHandler.java:607)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Connection$Dispatcher.channelRead0(Connection.java:1012)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Connection$Dispatcher.channelRead0(Connection.java:935)
    at io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:105)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:308)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:294)
    at io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.channelRead(IdleStateHandler.java:266)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:308)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:294)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:103)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:308)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:294)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:244)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:308)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:294)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:846)
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollStreamChannel$EpollStreamUnsafe.epollInReady(AbstractEpollStreamChannel.java:831)
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.processReady(EpollEventLoop.java:346)
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:254)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:111)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Will appreciate any suggestion how to solve it. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is in `someRdd`? I could imagine this my not be possible for some collections ?

Comment: there are instances of this `case class SomeObj(
  value: String,
  name: String,
  id: String,
  ts: Timestamp,
  tag: String,
  valid: Boolean
) extends Serializable`

the table description
`CREATE TABLE personal_ids (
  name TEXT,
  value TEXT,
  id TEXT,
  ts TIMESTAMP,
  tag TEXT,

  PRIMARY KEY ((name, value), id)
);`

Comment: Ok not sure about that, I would file a Jira with the Spark Cassandra Connector

Comment: What version of the datastax driver are you using?